# Calling WCF endpoint from Azure Function

Tags: azure, wcf, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a v2 Azure function written in dotnet core. I want to call in to a legacy WCF endpoint like this:

```
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService>(basicHttpBinding, null);
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "foo";
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "bar";

        IMyWcfService myWcfService = factory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpointUri)));

        ICommunicationObject communicationObject = myWcfService as ICommunicationObject;

        if ( communicationObject != null)
            communicationObject.Open();

        try
        {
            return await myWcfService.GetValueAsync());
        }            
        finally
        {

            if (communicationObject != null)
                communicationObject.Close();

            factory.Close();
        }
```

This works when I call it from a unit test, so I know the code is fine running on Windows 10. However, when I debug in the func host, I get missing dependency exceptions. I copied two dlls : `System.Private.Runtime` and `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime` into the in directory, but have reached the end of the line with the exception

> Could not load type 'System.Threading.Tasks.AsyncCausalityTracer' from assembly 'mscorlib'

This seems like a runtime rabbit hole that I don't want to go down. Has anyone successfully called a Wcf service from an Azure function? Which dependencies should I add to get the call to work?

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you running? [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/590) seems relevant.